# Kendoui Grid call custom function when nothing but text is returned

Tags: php, json, twitter-bootstrap, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Currently my PHP returns a json encoded string to the grid, which contains all the information needed to show the rows and cells in my grid.

But I want it to throw up a Bootstrap dialog box when plain text is returned instead of JSON.

How can this be done?

Comment: Why the down vote? Please have the sack to back it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add some validation logic into the parse method of the datasource, you should be able to do what you need.

http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#configuration-schema.parse

```
schema: {
    parse: function(response) {
     try
       {
               var json = $.parseJSON(response.data);
       }
       catch(err)
       {
               console.log('dialog');
       } 
      return response.data;
    }
  }
```